# Convert GMT to localtime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 102114 time format in SQL table.

This is GMT 0 and I want this in GMT +5:30, which means 155114.

Comment: what is the data type of that column ?

Comment: it is a bigint data type

Comment: Use the correct datatype, and this is much easier: [datetimeoffset (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). A `bigint` is the completely wrong choice for a time. The largest value you're going to store (in your format) would be 235959, which easily fits in an `int`.

Comment: But i want to convert in this format only

Comment: You can use 'SWITCHOFFSET' function.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2313/convert-sql-server-datetime-data-type-to-datetimeoffset-data-type/

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on using bigint then this is about the tidiest solution I can come up with, just replace the 102114 with the name of your column

```
    DATEADD(minute,330,cast(substring(cast(102114 AS nvarchar(10)),1,2) + ':' 
+ substring(cast(102114 AS nvarchar(10)),3,2) +':'
+ substring(cast(102114 AS nvarchar(10)),5,2) AS time))
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets the the result you want, however, there's a lot of conversions going on...

```
DECLARE @Time bigint; --This is really the wrong datatype here
SET @Time = 102114

SELECT CONVERT(bigint,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(MINUTE, 330, CONVERT(time,STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',6) + CONVERT(varchar(6), @Time),6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')))),':',''));
```

To demonstrate, however, how easy it is with the correct datatype though (`datetimeoffset`):

```
DECLARE @Time datetimeoffset;
SET @Time = '10:21:14';
SELECT @Time,SWITCHOFFSET(@Time, '+05:30');
```